# how to store same keys in different dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file where there are values

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key1:value3
key2:value4
```

i want to extracted the keys and values into a dictionary d, and the duplicated ones into another dictionary

like

`d={'key1':value1,'key2':value2}` and `e ={'key1':value3,'key2':value4}`

This is my code,what modification would be required??? and what can be done if more than two dictionaries are required?

```
d={}
e={}
L=[]
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as searchfile:

    for line in searchfile:
        line = line.strip()
        words=line.split(':')
        if words[0] in line:
            d[words[0]]=(words[1]
```

)

```
L.append(d)

print L
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? Well, I do not mind, but if a key is repeated more than twice... What would you do? Can you be more specific with the structure of the *file1.txt*?

Comment: Will keys show up exactly twice?

Comment: Yes in different dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
d={}
dict_lst = [d]
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as searchfile:

    for line in searchfile:
        line = line.strip()
        words=line.split(':')
        for d in dict_lst:
            if not d.has_key(words[0]):
                d[words[0]] = words[1]
                break
        else:
            new_d = {}
            new_d[words[0]] = words[1]
            dict_lst.append(new_d)
```

Comment: ok but what can be done if  more than two dictionaries are required?

Comment: @Kumar I have updates my answer. Anyway, I suggest you add your above comment to your question, as it's part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for any number of source files, e.g. `input.txt` and `input2.txt`.

It also keeps a count of the duplicates just in case there is more than one duplicate, meaning if there where three entries across all of the files with the same key, it would show two duplicates for that key:

```
import collections

d = {}
duplicates = {}
duplicate_counts = collections.Counter()

for input_file in ['input.txt', 'input2.txt']:
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f_input:
        for key_value in f_input:
            key, value = key_value.strip().split(':')
            if key in d:
                duplicates[key] = value
                duplicate_counts[key] += 1
            else:
                d[key] = value

print 'd:', d
print 'duplicates:', duplicates
print 'duplicate counts:', duplicate_counts
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for arbitrary number of dictionaries and uses [for-else](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) syntax.

> A break statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop
>   without executing the else clause’s suite.

```
dicts = [{}]
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        for d in dicts:
            if key not in d:
                d[key] = value
                break
        else:
            dicts.append({})
            dicts[-1][key] = value

print dicts
```

Given input file:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key1:value3
key2:value4
key1:value5
key3:value6
```

Output is:

```
[{'key3': 'value6', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'},
 {'key2': 'value4', 'key1': 'value3'},
 {'key1': 'value5'}]
```

Keep in mind that dictionaries are unordered, so 'key3' being in first position in first dict does not mean nothing (and these positions will change with different `PYTHONHASHSEED` anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the support

Comment: @Kumar you may want to accept one of answers (if they solves your problem).